# A question about axioms and logical implication

Tags: logic, axioms

I have a question about axioms and implication:
I just stumble upon various texts that use these concepts. like:

> Mathematicians have always looked for axioms in order to
>   find the fewest and simplest statements that imply all the other statements.

or

> Hilbert included an axiom in his The Foundations of Geometry that implies Dedekind's axiom.

or

> We show that in ZFA, set theory without the Axiom of Choice weakened to allow "atoms", Ingleton's axiom does not imply the Axiom of Choice.

or

> Huntington showed that the three axioms together imply the axioms of Boolean algebra.

and others like these.

I wanted to know when implies is used in these kinds of sentences, Is the word "implies" means like implication in logic or it has a different meaning?

I could have asked this question on other forums but I thought you would know better.

Comment: "Implies" means logically implies.  It means there's a mathematical argument beginning with the axioms in question and ending with the conclusion being referenced.  To show that a set of axioms *doesn't* imply something (as opposed to proving its opposite), the usual technique is to find some model that satisfies the axioms in question but fails to satisfy the conclusion you'd hoped those axioms prove.  That doesn't mean that the axioms refute the conclusion because there may be other models that *do* satisfy the conclusion.  But it certainly means that the axioms can't prove the conclusion.

Comment: The mean if we accept the hypothesis as true then the implication will also be true.  Ex:  Hilbert included an axiom.  If this axiom is assumed to be true then Dedekinds axiom is (can be shown to be) true.

Comment: Axioms belong to (axiomatic) *theories*. So, seeing from a wider perspective, they are just statements.

Comment: One other thing to note is that often the implication is relative to some implicit base theory. Like the 3rd quote explicitly gives the base theory ZFA (which it is constrasting with another possible base theory ZF), but I would guess the axiom in the second quote does not imply Dedekind’s axiom on its own, but rather implies it in the presence of some other axioms.

Comment: See [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) and e.g. [Hilbert’s *Foundations of Geometry*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-hilbert/#HilbFounGeom).

Comment: In all cases above "implies" is *logical implication* (or consequence).